# Amazon S3 rest Api "Get" request Authentication issue

Tags: amazon-s3, get, httprequest

i am trying to get an object from my amazon s3 account with a http call.

```
                string bucket = "rethymno";
                string path = "/aasdf.txt";
                string url = "http://" + bucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com" + path;

                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

                string now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string httpDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss +0000\n", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


                string AWSSecret = "xxx";
                string AWSKey = "xxx";

                string date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
                string region = "eu-central-1";
                string dTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");
                string sName = "s3";

                request.Method = "GET";
                request.Headers.Add("x-amz-date", dTime);
                request.Headers.Add("x-amz-content-sha256", "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855");
                request.Host= bucket+".s3.amazonaws.com";
                string authHead = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential="+ AWSKey + "/"+date + "/"+region + "/"+sName + "/aws4_request,"+"SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,"+"Signature="+ SignAuthorizationString(request, AWSSecret, date, region, path, sName, dTime);
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHead);
                HttpWebResponse res = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                MessageBox.Show(res.StatusCode.ToString());


private string SignAuthorizationString(HttpWebRequest request, string SecretKey, string date, string region, string path, string sName, string dTime)
        {

            string HTTPMethod = "GET";
            string CanonicalURI =  request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery;
            string CanonicalQueryString = "";
            string CanonicalHeaders = ComposeSignatureAmzHeadersForSigning(request);
            string SignedHeaders = "host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date";
            string HashedPayload = "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  ";
            string canonicalString2 = HTTPMethod+    "\n" +
                                      CanonicalURI + "\n" +
                                      CanonicalQueryString + "\n" +
                                      "host:"+request.Host + "\n" +
                                      CanonicalHeaders + "\n" +
                                      SignedHeaders + "\n" +
                                      HashedPayload;

            byte[] z = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(canonicalString2);
        SHA256Managed h = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hh = h.ComputeHash(z);
        string encodedCanonical = string.Empty;
        foreach (byte x in hh)
        {
            encodedCanonical += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
        }

            string encodedCanonical = ByteArrayToString(moreBytes);

            string stringToSign = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" + "\n" +
                                    dTime + "\n" +
                                    date + "/" + region + "/" + sName + "/aws4_request" + "\n" +
                                    encodedCanonical;


            byte[] SignatureBytes2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);

        sha256.Key = ae.GetBytes("AWS4" + SecretKey);
        byte[] DateKey = sha256.ComputeHash(ae.GetBytes(date.ToUpper()));
        sha256.Key = DateKey;
        byte[] DateRegionKey = sha256.ComputeHash(ae.GetBytes(region));
        sha256.Key = DateRegionKey;
        byte[] DateRegionServiceKey = sha256.ComputeHash(ae.GetBytes(sName));
        sha256.Key = DateRegionServiceKey;
        byte[] SigningKey = sha256.ComputeHash(ae.GetBytes("aws4_request"));

        sha256.Key = SigningKey;
        byte[] bytez = ae.GetBytes(stringToSign);
        byte[] moreBytez = sha256.ComputeHash(bytez);
        string sign = ByteArrayToString(moreBytez);
        return sign;
        }


 private string ComposeSignatureAmzHeadersForSigning(HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            SortedDictionary<string, string> headersDictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            foreach (string _key in request.Headers.Keys)
            {
                string key = _key.ToLower();
                if (key.StartsWith("x-amz"))
                {
                    if ("x-amz-meta-reviewedby".Equals(key))
                    {
                        if (headersDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
                            headersDictionary[key] = headersDictionary[key] + "," + request.Headers[key];
                        else
                            headersDictionary[key] = request.Headers[key];
                    }
                    else
                        headersDictionary[key] = request.Headers.Get(key);
                }
            }
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var pair in headersDictionary)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(pair.Key)
                    .Append(":")
                    .Append(pair.Value)
                    .Append("\n");

            }
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }


public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
        {
            string hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba).ToLower();
            return hex.Replace("-", "");
        }
```

When i try to receive file with path rethymno/aasdf.txt i get an 403 error.
when i made a test with post-man i got the error

> SignatureDoesNotMatch The request signature we calculated does not
>   match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

any suggestions?

Comment: Rather than pasting a large block of code and expecting people figure out what it is doing, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Try to narrow-down the question to a specific bit of code that is giving you issues.

Comment: i dont know where the problem might be that's why i paste a large block and believe me i didnt paste all  my code. Do you have any suggestion where might the problem be? @JohnRotenstein